New multisite Server Not Found
I've just created a multisite after many years of operating WooCommerce on one site alone.
I've added a new site that I wish to run another WC store on, but after adding the site I get a Server Not Found / 404 Not Found when navigating to it either directly or through the site dashboard.
I made a test index.html and that does load, so it would seem the the new site is blank? WooCommerce and all the other plugins are Network Activated - how do I get WC and the other plugins working on this new site?
Thanks

We need more information. What are the steps taken so far? Details matter. The more we know, the better the answer can be.

I didn't install the multisite in the same root folder as my WC installation. I resolved it by doing so.
